# Half of data lost between HAProxy and backend server

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy

I have a setup like this on Ubuntu

Browser --> HAProxy --> Backend server

The backend server is an ASP.NET Core web application.

It works 99.9% of the time except when a binary file is being uploaded (simple POST with multipart form-data), in which case I get the error:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component. 

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore.GetRequestTokensAsync(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

So, I have been trying to investigate why.

I tried the ASP.NET Core backend directly, it works.

So I logged the incoming data to the backend and found that if I do it directly then I get the expected request headers and then the uploaded file in the body.

Then I logged the incoming data to the backend via HAProxy and half of the data is missing.

Ie. the first data seen by the backend appears to be

```
04 E2 22 FC 60 FF 2B E1  BF 85 D2 75 F9 44 94 86
```

but these are the bytes roughly halfway through my file, which is 25,126 bytes.  I don't see any header info at all.

I am prepared to accept the my logging is imperfect and not necessarily accurate.  It seems like somehow the request was split in two, or a buffer has been filled and then written over.

What could the problem be?

```
global

    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    log /dev/log    local0 info

    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group users
    daemon
        
    lua-load /home/user/haproxy-mapping.lua

    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!AESCCM
    ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11 no-tls-tickets
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048


defaults
    log     global
    mode    http

    timeout connect 30000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close #have also try http-keep-alive


frontend httpfront
    mode http
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }


frontend web_front_end

    bind *:443 ssl crt /home/.....file.pem
    mode http

     log /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log local0 info

        # Rate limiting
        stick-table  type ip  size 100k  expire 600s  store http_req_rate(60s) #store up to 100k requests for 60s, see if over 60s there are more than 600
        http-request track-sc0 src
        http-request deny deny_status 429 if { sc_http_req_rate(0) gt 600 }


    # Ensure we have a clean state to start with
    http-request del-header X-SERVER-SNI

    # Set the concatenated value of the SNI value to a temporary header
    http-request set-header X-SERVER-SNI haproxy.%[ssl_fc_sni] if { ssl_fc_sni -m found }

    # Set the value of the header to a transaction-level variable
    http-request set-var(txn.fc_sni) ssl_fc_sni #hdr(X-SERVER-SNI) if { hdr(X-SERVER-SNI) -m found }

    #use Lua code to determine which backend to send to
    use_backend %[lua.legacy_new_backend]





backend backendnodes_1_https
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server node1 127.0.0.1:446 ssl verify none sni var(txn.fc_sni)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work properly now with HAProxy config

```
option http-keep-alive
```

instead of

```
option http-server-close
```

I would have sworn that I tried it before, but it does make sense that it helps.